# Magento 2 Payment Getway Options

Tags: magento2, paypal, payment-gateway

I need to add payment gateway in my Magento2 store,

I need to add three options credit card, debit card, and paypal.

I can see lots of options in Magento configuration, but I am not able to understand, from where should I start?

It is really urgent. it will be great if anyone can help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try using Braintree as the Payment Method, they are able to collect Credit Card, Debit Card and Paypal payments.

Learn More from the Magento 2 user guide 
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/payment/braintree.html